# C++ variable type conditional

Tags: c++, c++11, types

I have two Classes `TreeNodeRange(Tree & t)` and `VertexNodeRange(Vertex & v)`. Looping over the first is equal to looping over all nodes in a tree whereas looping over the second is equal to looping over all nodes that a children to a given vertex v.

Now depending on user input I would like to either loop over the whole tree or only the subtree that starts at v.

I tried something like this:

```
const bool only_subtree = to_bool(argv[1]);
typedef std::conditional<only_subtree, VertexNodeRange,TreeNodeRange>::type NodeRange;
```

The problem is now that I don't see how I can define an object of type NodeRange. I tried:

```
Vertex v = tree.get_vertex_by_id(17);
NodeRange get_range = [&](const bool only_subtree, Vertex & v)
    {
        if(only_subtree) return NodeRange(v);
        return NodeRange(tree);
    };
for(auto node : get_range(only_subtree, v)){
    ...
}
```

The compiler doesn't seem to like this since the constructor NodeRange must be callable with either Vertex or Tree which of course it does not.

It there a way to do this in C++ at all?

Cheers

Comment: Sounds like a job for polymorphism.

Comment: I should have said that theses classes are defined in external libraries that I don't have direct access to.

Comment: Then make polymorphic wrappers for them?

Comment: C++14 makes this much easier.  Do you have C++14?

Comment: Yes I do. How could I do it in C++14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a template function:

```
template<typename AnyNodeRange>
void processChildNodes(AnyNodeRange& anyNodeRange)
{
    for(auto node : anyNodeRange){
    ...
    }
}
```

and use it like this :

```
Vertex v = tree.get_vertex_by_id(17);
if (only_subtree) {
    VertexNodeRange vertexNodeRange(v);
    processChildNodes(vertexNodeRange);
}
else 
{
    TreeNodeRange treeNodeRange(tree);
    processChildNodes(treeNodeRange);
}
```

You cannot make typedefs using only_subtree, because it is user input, only known at runtime, where as types are only defined at compilation time.